# How to loop for create a multi-page TIFF (Layer Stack)

Tags: python, gdal

So far I use python to create a layer stack for each pair of TIF files now l am looking for the solution to loop this process.

This is my code for creating a layer stack.

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
imgB01Path = "E:/eyerStack/Raw2Tif_2016/tif16/2016.01.01.Smb01.tif"
imgB02Path = "E:/eyerStack/Raw2Tif_2016/tif16/2016.01.01.Smb02.tif"
outImgPath = "E:/LeyerStack2016/2016.01.01.tif"

oB01Band = gdal.Open(imgB01Path)
oB02Band = gdal.Open(imgB02Path)

gDriver = oB01Band.GetDriver()
outImg = gDriver.Create(outImgPath, oB01Band.RasterXSize,oB01Band.RasterYSize, 2, gdal.GDT_UInt16, ["PHOTOMETRIC=RGB"])

outImg.SetGCPs(tuple(oB01Band.GetGCPs()),oB01Band.GetGCPProjection()) #Set GCPs
outImg.SetGeoTransform(tuple(oB01Band.GetGeoTransform())) #Set GeoTransform
outImg.SetProjection(oB01Band.GetProjection()) #Set Projection

B01 = oB01Band.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
B02 = oB02Band.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

outImg.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(B01)
outImg.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(B02)

oB01Band = None #Clear Memory
oB02Band = None #Clear Memory
outImg = None #Clear Memory
```

The example file name of band1

```
2015.01.01.Smb01.tif
2015.01.09.Smb01.tif
2015.01.17.Smb01.tif
2015.01.25.Smb01.tif
2015.02.02.Smb01.tif
```

The example file name of band2

```
2015.01.01.Smb02.tif
2015.01.09.Smb02.tif
2015.01.17.Smb02.tif
2015.01.25.Smb02.tif
2015.02.02.Smb02.tif
```

This is the complete adapted code.

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

tifFolder = r'E:/ProcessNdvi2015_2021/05LayerStack/tif/'

tifs = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, folder, files in os.walk(tifFolder) for file in files if file.endswith('tif') and 'smb' in file.lower()]
tifs.sort()
count = 0
for t1, t2 in zip(tifs[::2], tifs[1::2]):
    ##print(t1,t2)
    oB01Band = gdal.Open(tifs[count])
    oB02Band = gdal.Open(tifs[count+1])
    filename = tifs[count].split("/")[-1]
    
    outImgPath = "E:/ProcessNdvi2015_2021/05LayerStack/LayerStack2/" + filename 

    gDriver = oB01Band.GetDriver()
    outImg = gDriver.Create(outImgPath, oB01Band.RasterXSize,oB01Band.RasterYSize, 2, gdal.GDT_Int16, ["PHOTOMETRIC=RGB"])

    outImg.SetGCPs(tuple(oB01Band.GetGCPs()),oB01Band.GetGCPProjection()) #Set GCPs
    outImg.SetGeoTransform(tuple(oB01Band.GetGeoTransform())) #Set GeoTransform
    outImg.SetProjection(oB01Band.GetProjection()) #Set Projection

    B01 = oB01Band.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    B02 = oB02Band.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

    outImg.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(B01)
    outImg.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(B02)

    oB01Band = None #Clear Memory
    oB02Band = None #Clear Memory
    outImg = None #Clear Memory
    count = count+2
```

Comment: You should be able to write a simple filename glob (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and set up your path based on that. It may need some error checking to make sure that the band1 and band2 files are both present. I don't think there is anything GIS specific in the python code you'd need to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like os walk in combination with [collections defaultdict list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for problems like this. You can store each date as a key, and the two files as values:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

tifFolder = r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/'

tifs = defaultdict(list)

for root, folders, files in os.walk(tifFolder): #Find all tif files with smb in filename in the tifFolder
    for file in files:
        if 'smb' in file.lower() and file.endswith('tif'):
            tifs[file.split('.S')[0]].append(os.path.join(root, file)) #Add the full path to the file as value and date as key to the defaultdict
           
#defaultdict(list,
            #{'2015.01.01': ['/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.01.Smb01.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.01.Smb02.tif'],
             #'2015.01.09': ['/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.09.Smb01.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.09.Smb02.tif'],
             #'2015.01.17': ['/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.17.Smb02.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.17.Smb01.tif']})

for date, tiffiles in tifs.items():
    smb01, smb02 = sorted(tiffiles) #You will get ValueError here if there's missing files
    print(date)
    print(smb01)
    print(smb02)
    #oB01Band = gdal.Open(smb01)
    #oB02Band = gdal.Open(smb02)
    # ...
    

#2015.01.01
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.01.Smb01.tif
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.01.Smb02.tif

#2015.01.09
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.09.Smb01.tif
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.09.Smb02.tif

#2015.01.17
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.17.Smb01.tif
#/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/input_files/2015.01.17.Smb02.tif
```

You can also try something like this, which is easier:

```
import os

tifFolder = r'C:\Users\jksdhfd\Desktop\Temp'

tifs = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, folder, files in os.walk(tifFolder) for file in files if file.endswith('tif') and 'smb' in file.lower()]
tifs.sort()

for t1, t2 in zip(tifs[::2], tifs[1::2]):
    print(t1, t2)
```