# How to Mosaic to Raster multiple combinations in dataset

Tags: arcpy, mosaic, multiple

I am trying to Mosaic to Raster differing combinations of rasters based on portions of their names.

I have only rasters in a GDB for with the following naming convention example:

```
g203_DEP_0035Y_OW_LS, g203_DEP_0035Y_OW_S, g203_WSE_0035Y_OW_LS, g203_WSE_0035Y_OW_S g203_DEP_0750Y_OW_LS, g203_DEP_0750Y_OW_S, g203_WSE_0750Y_OW_LS, g203_WSE_0750Y_OW_S
```

My need is to merge rasters with WSE's or DEP's with the same return periods.

I have put something together that seems to somewhat work for a single set but am looking for a solution so that I can iterate through all needed scenarios as I am dealing with many more than two return periods.
Here is the script that can run based on one set of parameters:

```
import os
import arcpy

Link_ID = "g203"
env.workspace = r"M:\MyProject\RastersDraft.gdb"
outLocation = r"M:\MyProject\RastersFinal.gdb"

rasters = []
print(rasters)

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(arcpy.env.workspace, topdown=True)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
    # Append the feature class to the fcs list
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

        arcpy.management.MosaicToNewRaster(workspace, output_location, "merged_WSE_0035", "", "", "", "1", "FIRST", "")
print("Processing Completed")
```

Comment: Try using collections.defaultdict, to group by link_id see an example here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431265/how-to-loop-for-create-a-multi-page-tiff-layer-stack/431268#431268

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create **unmanaged** raster catalog, add field depicting group name. Experiment with expression to populate this field until you are happy with them:

[image]

Next step: summarize this field into separate table:

[image]

Now you can shuffle through smaller table and SQL select relevant raster names from your catalog to be mosaicked. I would also update PROGRESS field to monitor and skip already processed groups, because such big tasks can result in memory collapse and you'll need to re-run your script.